# Can you customize JaCoCo output files?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

We have a large codebase with multiple languages and are trying to standardize the metric via which code coverage is measured currently. We're wondering if it is possible to have our code coverage tool create a custom HTML output that would be the same across tools. The one we are testing with right now is JaCoCo and we're trying to see if JaCoCo can create an HTML file of code coverage. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is another tool that might suit our needs? We initially tried looking for a code coverage tool that works with multiple languages (python, java, nodejs, etc). Thanks in advance!

Edit: Looks like SonarQube might be exactly what we're looking for! Thanks

Comment: Just wondering, doesn't SonarQube solve this problem?

Comment: Sonarqube displays your analysis on a per repo basis, I haven't played with SonarQube in a while, it might have a plugin for that

Answer (score 1):

Jacoco can create a bunch of formats, html, xml, json, pdf. What I would recommend in your case is to retrieve the generated Jacoco Reports, store your data in any mechanism you seem suitable and then build your own custom UI from the data you have.

Comment: hmm yea I didn't think about that. That sounds like a solid solution actually. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to assist

Comment: There is an open PR with the ask that isn't prioritised by the maintainers and needs some community love: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/382